# Why do parameter changes have to be smooth homeomorphisms?

Tags: curves, parametrization

(This is about parametrized curves in $\mathbb{R^n}$.)

In my book, a **parameter change** is defined as a bijection $\varphi: J \to I$ between intervals of $\mathbb{R}$ s.t. both $\varphi$ and $\varphi^{-1}$ are **smooth**.

Why do they have to be **smooth**? I can understand they have to be continuous. What problems would arise if you didn't force them to be smooth (i.e. $\varphi$ is any homeomorphism between $J$ and $I$)?

Comment: This is just a definition of a term.  If this is a differential geometry book, they probably want a parameter change to take smooth curves to smooth curves.

Comment: @BrianMoehring taking smooth curves to smooth curves makes sense, I think that answers my question.